# explicit typecast float to byte

Tags: java, casting, integer-overflow

How does the explicit typecast from float to byte work in Java and why is the last output also -1 and not 0? The first output of 57 is probably due to the arithmetic overflow, so the addition of 1 yields to 58, which makes sense to me. But therefore I expected the last output to be 0.

```
public class Typecasts {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        float f = 12345.0f;
        byte b = (byte) f;
        System.out.println(b); // output: 57
        b = (byte) (f + 1);
        System.out.println(b); // output: 58
        f = 12345678987654321.0f;
        b = (byte) f;
        System.out.println(b); // output: -1
        b = (byte) (f + 1);
        System.out.println(b); // output: -1
    }

}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with casting to byte. The value of `12345678987654321.0f` is so large, that 1 is too small to give it another value (that is `12345678987654321.0f == 12345678987654321.0f + 1` is **true**). You need to add around`1E9f` to get another value! .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conversion from `float` to `byte` is a *narrowing primitive conversion*, which may cause discarding of most significant bytes, according to the Java Language Specification § 5.1.

However, the real problem lies here: a large number like `12345678987654321.0` *already* has loss of precision, even before the typecast is performed. Printing out the value of `f` will already hint this:

```
1.23456795E16
```

See Java Language Specification § 4.2.3 and [§ 4.2.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.4):

> Floating-point arithmetic is carried out in accordance with the rules of the IEEE 754 Standard, including for overflow and underflow.

Also, the [JLS § 15.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.4) defines how floating-point expressions should be carried out. It's a little technical to read, but in short, it'll discard least significant bits because of *underflow*.

So in your case, `f + 1` will result in just `f`.

Comment: In this case, there is a loss of most significant digits (the magnitude of the number).